# access d3 __data__ attribute in PhantomJS when testing angular directive

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, phantomjs

I have an problem accessing the __data__ attribute when doing tests in PhantomJS.

Basically, I just want to do

```
var lineChart =  $compile('<div line-chart></div>')($rootScope);
$rootScope.$digest();
expect($(lineChart).find('.lines path')[0].__data__.value.length).toBe(27);
```

It works fine in chrome, but not in PhantomJS. 
Looks like the phantomJS only work if using .eq(1) .html() etc
so I switch to

`$(lineChart).find('.lines path').eq(0).__data__)`

to grab the element but it still doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to grab the d3 __data__ attribute within PhantomJS?

Comment: a workaround would be to use d3 selector, like d3.selectAll('.lines path')[0][0].__data__ But to do this, you have to create a d3 container to wrap everything, which is not convenient for testing directive. Still curious about how to access the private(_) variable in PhantomJS?